# Winform app After obfuscation with smart assembly throw entity framework exception

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, obfuscation, smartassembly

I developed a software in windows form. I used entity framework (code first) approach. When the app starts its communicate with database, while communicating entity framework throws an exception, which I'm unable to interpret.
(note: it happens only after obfuscation. I'm using SmartAssembly 6.9).. without obfuscation, all is correct.

I posted this problem in below link today at morning .. but didn't receive response. I'm giving link below
https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/81758/entity-framework-code-first-exception-after-obfuscating-net-assembly#latest

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this before you post any more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'd be surprised if you found anyone here, that could understand the "obfuscation" process of a third party software with that limited info you have supplied... to note, thousands of companies/developers world-wide don't use such a service.... "Keep it simple...."

Comment: Definitely SmartAssembly is 3rd party's software, and how it does obfuscation ? I'm not asking and concerned about it.. well .. it is pretty clear what I hv asked. I thought may be someone have faced the same problem before, he/she can help. I'm googling last since last 30 hours and trying obfuscation with different options, but all the time same problem ... so at last I came here ... I received your response... So tell me what more or extra information you required. I will provide.

Comment: @Maciej Jureczko .. thanks dear, I have already read before posting my question. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A feature of smart assembly is the ability to decode obfuscated stack traces.  I would check their documentation on how you can do this so you can debug your program.

Comment: I will be more than thankful to you. I myself is working hard to address this problem.